# struts2 spring project to run on jetty and tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jetty

I am working on a web project which I can successfully deploy on Tomcat. Now I want to run the project in jetty. I created a main method which starts jetty. jetty starts at port 8080, but showing `error 500 JSP support not configured` so i add **jetty jsp** dependency. then it throw an exception `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /common/taglibs.jsp(2,80) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` (where **taglib.jsp** contains different tag-libs)

Then  When I run it on tomcat it starts up with some info `INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined`

and when I start it gives `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;Lorg/apache/jasper/runtime/ProtectedFunctionMapper;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;`

**maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>${jettyjsp.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT 1:**
 when I add `<scope>provided</scope>` to the dependency tomcat starts successfully but when starting jetty it still gives the following stack trace

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /common/taglibs.jsp(2,80) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:169)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:429)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:234)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:579)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1649)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:239)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:156)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:428)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:571)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1649)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:239)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:140)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:431)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:366)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.JspPropertyGroupServlet.service(JspPropertyGroupServlet.java:127)
```

Comment: I was using a version 7.6.10 and i changed to 8.1.10.v20130312 . there was some conflicting jar's when i exclude those jars it worked fine.( without using jetty-maven-plugin)

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy could you please help me with this [create a executable jar using maven and jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20491407/2334391)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing different problems.

## Jetty concerns

**You must NOT declare jetty as a dependency, but as a plugin, if you really want to run it as a server.**

Jetty would work just adding these lines to your pom.xml :

#### Recent version of plugin

```xml
<build>
    <!-- MORE CONF HERE -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.v20130308</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maybe more plugins here -->
    </plugins>
    <!-- EVEN MORE Build CONF HERE -->
</build>
```

#### Or older versions (like in my projects)

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.3.v20120416</version>
</plugin>
```

They are many available plugin configurations, but the basic one is sufficient.

#### More info :

- [maven jetty - org.mortbay.jetty vs org.eclipse.jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386461/maven-jetty-org-mortbay-jetty-vs-org-eclipse-jetty)
- http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#get-up-and-running

## Servlet API issues

Your java.lang.NoSuchMethodError means that you are trying to run your app, with an embedded Servlet API in a version, say version A, against a server running it in another one, say version B. These versions are incompatible.

You should declare Servlet API only as provided, not the default scope (compile), and make sure that your server support it.

Comment: is it necessary to add a plugin when i am adding jar as dependency

Comment: It is not the saim goal. Dependencies are basically libs that will be used by your code during run, or test (like Spring, Struts 2, ...). Plugins are intended for a maven use, to enhance basic behaviour (adding reporting, use different compilation options, ...). So jetty must be used as a plugin, not a dependency.

Comment: in that case if i want to start the jetty server from a main method how can i achieve using a plug-in ,you really want a dependency jar right?

Comment: I see two different cases. Either you really want to manage servers because you are developping a kind of scheduler, so you'll obviouslt need dependencies.  Or you need some extra components during tests / build/ , like a database / a ldap / a mock server ..., and so you should integrate them within the lifecycle projet through plugins, like. Then it could be a dependency (like H2 database server) or Spring Component (like ldap embedded server) or a dedicated plugin (like jetty) or even a general plugin (maven-exec-plugin).