# package org.mortbay.http does not exist. How to add dependencies for this in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pom.xml, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to build my java project using maven. While compiling I'm getting the following error -

```
package org.mortbay.http does not exist 
package org.mortbay.jetty does not exist 
package org.mortbay.jetty.servlet does not exist
```

I have added these dependencies at the last of my `pom.xml` file -

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.15.v20161220</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.25</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using `SocketListener listener = new SocketListener();` and `ServletHttpContext` classes. What changes do I need to make in my java class ?

Answer (score 1):

`org.mortbay.jetty` have been replaced by `org.eclipse.jetty` (see [maven jetty - org.mortbay.jetty vs org.eclipse.jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386461/maven-jetty-org-mortbay-jetty-vs-org-eclipse-jetty#15387163)).

You should use the following dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
</dependency>
```

and the packages :

- `org.eclipse.jetty.server`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.http`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets`

Also, try to avoid mixing different versions of Jetty artifacts.

Comment: What changes will I have to make in my java classes ?

Comment: 8 years have passed since the last version of `org.mortbay.jetty:jetty` (`6.1.26`), so the API and internals have quite changed. You can find more info in the [current documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html), or you can find some guides to migrate.

Comment: note: `jetty-servlet` (singular, support for javax.servlet) and `jetty-servlets` (plural, extra servlets for projects to use) are different things.

Answer (score 0):

I found the right version for the dependency that covers for all the errors that I was getting.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

With this dependency I was able to build my project and export a jar out of it.